# Access Google Drive files from a web query

Tags: python, web-applications, google-drive-api

I want to allow users to access Google Drive files, whose permission is set to Public(Anyone with a link can access , no sign-in required), via a web interface.

The scenario is like this:

There will be a web form asking for a input.

e.g If the user provides an ID No. 38752 , the user should be able to retrieve 38752.pdf by clicking a button say 'Download'

Means, we will accept an input and from that redirect to the public link of the concerned file.

Edit:

Let me explain the scenario in more detail. We want to generate laboratory reports in PDF format(in that case we are the owner of the files) and want the patients to access it through a web interface, in which they are supposed to provide the 'Lab ID' only. I plan to store the auto-generated PDF reports in the Google Drive folder in the Hard Disk so that they will automatically uploaded. The names will be Lab_ID.pdf. As Lab_IDs are unique, so filenames should be unique. Now, the only job is to give the patients, the links to their concerned 'Lab_ID.pdf' files, so that they can download them.

Comment: Well, I am actually inviting ideas. Any idea where to begin?

Comment: You should first make the question more clear. For example, some of the things I did not understand after reading your question -:  
1. Whose files do you want to expose exactly?  
2. Taking file names as inputs might be ambiguous as multiple files might have same names. Instead, you should take file ID's which are unique.  
3. In the example you gave, from where did the extension '.pdf' come from?  
4. If the file access permissions are such that they are only accessible through a link, then wouldn't it be impossible to make them accessible in the way you want them?

Comment: Let me explain the scenario in more detail. We want to generate laboratory reports in PDF format(in that case we are the owner of the files) and want the patients to access it through a web interface, in which they are supposed to provide the 'Lab ID' only. I plan to store the auto-generated PDF reports in the Google Drive folder in the Hard Disk so that they will automatically uploaded. The names will be Lab_ID.pdf. As Lab_IDs are unique, so filenames should be unique. Now, the only job is to give the patients, the links to their concerned 'Lab_ID.pdf' files, so that they can download them.

Comment: Okay! Add this information to the question; you'll have a better chance of getting answers that way.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you wanted is already in [Google Drive SDK](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk)

Upload your file using [Manage Upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads)

Download file using [Manage Downloads](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads)

Restrict the file to be downloaded only by a certain users [Manage Sharing](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-sharing)

Hope this helps